# same class, different size...?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

See the code, then you would understand what I'm confused.

Test.h

```
class Test {
public:
#ifndef HIDE_VARIABLE
    int m_Test[10];
#endif
};
```

Aho.h

```
class Test;

int GetSizeA();
Test* GetNewTestA();
```

Aho.cpp

```
//#define HIDE_VARIABLE
#include "Test.h"
#include "Aho.h"

int GetSizeA() { return sizeof(Test); }
Test* GetNewTestA() { return new Test(); }
```

Bho.h

```
class Test;

int GetSizeB();
Test* GetNewTestB();
```

Bho.cpp

```
#define HIDE_VARIABLE   // important!
#include "Test.h"
#include "Bho.h"

int GetSizeB() { return sizeof(Test); }
Test* GetNewTestB() { return new Test(); }
```

TestPrj.cpp

```
#include "Aho.h"
#include "Bho.h"
#include "Test.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int a = GetSizeA();
    int b = GetSizeB();

    Test* pA = GetNewTestA();
    Test* pB = GetNewTestB();

    pA->m_Test[0] = 1;
    pB->m_Test[0] = 1;

    // output : 40     1
    std::cout << a << '\t' << b << std::endl;

    char temp;
    std::cin >> temp;

    return 0;
}
```

Aho.cpp does not `#define HIDE_VARIABLE`, so `GetSizeA()` returns 40, but
Bho.cpp does `#define HIDE_VARIABLE`, so `GetSizeB()` returns 1.
But, `Test* pA` and `Test* pB` both have member variable m_Test[].

If the size of class `Test` from `Bho.cpp` is 1, then pB is weird, isn't it?

I don't understand what's going on, please let me know.
Thanks, in advance.

Environment:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 SP1 (or SP2?)

Comment: And what did you expect?

Comment: @ruslik: My guess would be that P-P expects the statement `pB->m_Test[0]` to not compile, or at least to fail at runtime, because class `Test` is defined without the member variable `m_Test` in the translation unit where `GetNewTestB()` is defined.

Comment: Billy ONeal knows what I want.

Comment: @`P-P`: If you're compiling in debug mode, when you try to `delete pB` it will probably crash like you're expecting because MSVC inserts canaries to detect this sort of thing in debugging builds. In release mode it might or might not be caught.

Comment: @P-P `main()` sees the whole definition of `Test`, so it will compile. However, it could produce memory corruption, because the actual reserved size was smaller. I expect that you have to write into at least `m_Test[4]` for that to actually happen.

Comment: @P-P memory is committed in pages (usually 4kb) (or even more if you use heap and not `VirtualAlloc()` for each allocation). Did you expect each byte to have an `used` flag?

Comment: @ruslik @Billy when I added pB->m_Test[9] = 9; crash happeded at std::cout lines. So, I think Test* pB looks like it has m_Test but it doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You violated the requirements of One Definition Rule (ODR). The behavior of your program is undefined. That's the only thing that's going on here.

According to ODR, classes with external linkage have to be defined *identically* in all translation units.

Comment: Wow.. we posted at the exact same time -- to the *second*! +1

Comment: @AndreyT Yeah, cause both of you evidently never heard about PIMPL.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: The Op's code violates ODR. Period. This has nothing to do with whichever idiom the code uses

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I'm eagerly waiting for your explanation of the role different definitions of the same class play in PIMPL. (And difference in definitions is actually the point of the question).

Comment: @AndreyT That is irrelevant. For god sake, this is obviously demonstration code. I (and other teachers) use similar codes all the time. Of course you can't share the `Test` class between translation units, but that's not the point. The point is that interfacing using a pointer allows you to shield the code from the actual definition.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Did you read the question? The OP is asking specifically about strange return values from two different translation units that define `Test` differently.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Oh, and most ALL code you'll see in questions is going to be demonstration code. Real code deals with extraneous problems like error handling that aren't often relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: and I don't know where you see the pimpl idiom in there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

Answer (score 13):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior. You are violating the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (class `Test` is defined differently in two places). Therefore the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants, including "weird" behavior.

Comment: @Billy Because this code is a demonstration of PIMPL and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Since when does PIMPL suddenly involves defining the same class differently in different translation units?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: class `Test` is defined differently in different translation units. That's undefined. You can use the pimpl idiom to hide changes in the implementation of the class, yes, but at link time all definitions of a class have to be the same. The pimpl idiom stops one from having to recompile everything, but everything still needs to be relinked, precisely because of this.

Comment: @Billy Is it really undefined? Splitting the two Test classes into two different namespaces would definitely make it well defined, but I don't think that this case is actually involves undefined behaviour. The definition is never exposed.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Splitting the test classes into different namespaces removes the violation of ODR. But as written, it does violate ODR and is therefore undefined.

Comment: @Billy Does it? In ODR you need to have one definition per translation unit. And the definition is never exported from the translations units.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: No, ODR says one definition per **program**, not translation unit. The compiler is required to diagnose the violations that occur whithin a single translation unit, but no diagnosis is required when the issue spans translation units. From here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf 3.2.3 : `Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is
used in that program; no diagnostic required.`

Comment: @Billy OK, it does break the ODR because multiple definitions are only allowed if "each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens", which is not true here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ODR.

Most of the grief is caused by including the headers only in the cpp files, allowing you to change the definition between the compilation units.

> But, Test* pA and Test* pB both have member variable m_Test[].

No, pB doesn't have `m_Test[]` however the TestPrj compilation unit doesn't know that and is applying the wrong structure of the class so it will compile.
Unless you compile in debug with capturing of memory overrun you would most times not see a problem.
`pB->m_Test[9] = 1;` would cause writing to memory not assigned by pB but may or may not be a valid space for you to write.

Comment: yes, that's right. after pB->m_Test[9] = 1; the program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Like many people told here, you've violated the so-called One Definition Rule (ODR).

It's important to realize how C/C++ programs are assembled. That is, the translation units (cpp files) are compiled **separately**, without any connection to each other. Next linker assembles the executable according to the symbols and the code pieces generated by the compiler. It doesn't have any high-level type information, hence it's unable (and should not) to detect the problem.

So that you've actually cheated the compiler, beaten yourself, shoot your foot, whatever you like.

One point that I'd like to mention is that actually ODR rule is violated very frequently due to subtle changes in the various include header files and miscellaneous defines, but usually there's no problem and people don't even realize this.

For instance a structure may have a member of `LPCTSTR` type, which is a pointer to either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on the defines, includes and etc. But this type of violation is "almost ok". As long as you don't actually use this member in differently compiled translation units there's no problem.

There're also many other common examples. Some arise from the in-class implemented member functions (inlined), which actually compile into different code within different translation units (due to different compiler options for different translation units for instance).

However this is usually ok. In your case however the **memory layout** of the structure has changed. And here we have a real problem.

Comment: +1 because this is a good explanation of how C++ compilation works, -1 because undefined behavior is NEVER OKAY. Total: 0.

Comment: Then you miss the point. I mean that strictly speaking ODR is **almost always** violated, whether you want or not. Different translation units can't have 100% the same compiler settings + state. In the term "one rule definition" there's a problem with "definition". Since things are defined when they're compiled. And compiler is a complex state machine.

Comment: @valdo: Differing settings are a programmer error. I don't see what effect what differing state has on the definition of the class. The one definition rule is a programmer rule, not a compiler implementor rule. Compilers are free to handle that however they wish. ODR has absolutely nothing to do with the relationship between the compiler and the linker w.r.t. the C++ standard, because the C++ standard doesn't define the relationship between these two.

Comment: @valdo:  If you almost always violate the ODR and produce code with undefined behavior, that's one thing.  Don't speak for me and my code.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: imagine you implement a function inside a class declaration. This is allowed in C++. Now imagine you include the header file of this class in two different cpp files. Which have, for instance, different exception handling settings. The code will be **different**.

Comment: @valdo: And which would exhibit undefined behavior.